# Building a library of canonical questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Following [this discussion](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3487/21067), I think we should "build a library" of canonical questions (on meta) that are off-topic for the IPS format but still interesting.

The question is:

- What format do we want to use for those canonical questions?
- What kind of question do we want? Are they some that we *don't* want?

---

**For the format**, I think we have two main possibilities here:

- Each canonical question are posted as a new answer for the same meta question
- Each canonical question has its separate question and answers

For the format of each canonical question, I'll wait and see what you think.

**About the questions we want**, I have already ideas:

- How to support my sexually assaulted friend?
- How to know if you are in an abusive relationship?
- How to help my depressed/suicidal friend?

So, what do you think?

Comment: What would make questions off-topic for IPS suitable on meta? Either their format is problematic, which makes them unanswerable on main, I don't see how moving them to meta fixes that. If it is the topic rather than the format, I would wonder even more so whether that has any place on IPS whatsoever.

Comment: @JAD This was suggested several times in the answers there: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3487/21067 Also, I know something similar has been done on Worldbuilding, unfortunately, I can't find the meta link again (Tinkeringbell gave it to me in chat).

Comment: @JAD Also, I believe that the example questions I posted are important questions and that we should, somehow, be able to link to relevant resources to answer them. Like posting a link to wikiHow with a summary for the question "How to know if you are in an abusive relationship?"

Comment: I think we need to be careful with treating meta as a catch-all for off-topic questions on main. Just because a question deserves an answer, doesn't mean that IPS (main or meta) is the place to put those. Creating a meta question with frequently used sources on some topics that are often touched on IPS is fine, to link to whenever needed. But that does not mean that any semi-IPS related question should instead be posted on Meta.

Comment: @JAD I agree with that. Thus my question about what we **want** and what we **don't want** as IPS canonical questions. Maybe every possible canonical meta questions should be voted on meta first before being allowed to be posted and answered?

Comment: I wonder what the problem is with letting this happen in an organic way? Post them when they appear, instead of planning and hashing out all possible options.

Comment: @JAD The question "How to know if you are in an abusive relationship?" appeared recently and was closed. I really want to answer it because it's an important question. But how do I format that? Isn't it something the community should discuss first?

Comment: Judging from the meta about that question, it was both off-topic and too broad. I'm not sure if moving the question to meta solves either of them really. It sounds a bit to me like an answer in search of a question, and if all else fails, just put that question on meta. I don't think that's necessarily the way forward.

Comment: @JAD I'm not planning in moving this question to meta. What I think we should do is to post a new meta question asking "How to know if you are in an abusive relationship?" (and just that, no additional context) and then answering with: here is where you can find help about this (put interesting links here, like [this wikiHow article](https://www.wikihow.com/Recognize-a-Potentially-Abusive-Relationship))

Answer (score 4):

> Building a library...

I'll make the answer almost as short as the question : **libraries have books, SE have Q/A**.

> ...of canonical questions?

here, "*canonical*" sounds like (kind of) "*rhetorical*". And that's **not** (at all) the SE/IPS format.

I realize that it's a bit harsh. Maybe it is. Too much. And if it is, I'll apologize. But that's exactly the short answer that I think needs to be done sometimes, like when we say that "***NO*** is a complete sentence". And that not too many explanations shouldn't be given. Here, though, we should provide people with explanations, so, here are my 3 cents, as you have 3 bullets in your question.

- What format do we want to use for those canonical questions? -> **none**? (because it doesn't fit our SE format?  Op-Based / Too-B. / Off-T. / ...).
- What kind of question do we want? -> the one we can answer, because they have a real problem, a real goal, an IPS solution, and they respect the SE format, I'd say.
- Are they some that we don't want? -> all of the others? ;)

---

Short story long now, just from some of your examples:

- *How to support my sexually assaulted friend?* -> it depends on the friend/age/perpetrator/so-many-factors-you-can-name-and-add... it's far too broad, and words and actions will vary depending on the relationship(s), the personality (both you and your friend)... and so on...
- *How to know if you are in an abusive relationship?* -> was already discussed on meta.
- How to help my depressed/suicidal friend? -> was already discussed on meta and an answer was given, so that one can copy/paste just in case.

---

And just because @JAD already used (in comments) the words and sentences I was about to write, no need to lose time, I'll just quote them, then:

- > What would make questions off-topic for IPS suitable on meta? Either their format is problematic, which makes them unanswerable on main, I don't see how moving them to meta fixes that.
- > I think we need to be careful with treating meta as a catch-all for off-topic questions on main. Just because a question deserves an answer, doesn't mean that IPS (main or meta) is the place to put those" (end of quote - My thought: even with links, we're not a "*regular/normal*" forum).
- > Judging from the meta about that question, it was both off-topic and too broad. I'm not sure if moving the question to meta solves either of them really. It sounds a bit to me like an answer in search of a question, and if all else fails, just put that question on meta.